# Add content to a div without refreshing iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a div, and the div has an iframe with a game.
I want to add content to that div, below the iframe, but when I do it, the iframe (also that textarea) refreshes.

I want to

- Add HTML content to the div
- Don't modify the preexisting content.
- If possible, without JQuery

I know the effect of DOM replacing, I just wanted this could be possible. The problem is, I can't create a dedicated div just for it because the iframe and the text area themselves area supposed to be part of the changing div (the iframe can be added to the chat log, using some "BBCode" here in the chat)

I appreciate your patience.

```js
function send()
{

if($('sendtxt').value == ":custom:"){
  $('content').innerHTML += "<br>" + "<textarea>this text also refresh</textarea>";
  $('sendtxt').value = "";
} else {
  $('content').innerHTML += "<br>" + $('sendtxt').value;
  $('sendtxt').value = "";
}

}

function $(id)
{

return document.getElementById(id);

}
```

```css
#content {
  
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  background-color:#222;
  color:white;
}

textarea, input {

  display:inline-block;
}

textarea {
  width:calc(100%);
  height:50px;
}

input[type="button"]{
  margin:0;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  right:10px;
  top:5px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
The iframe doesn't seem to work in here. but the textarea have the same effect.

<textarea placeholder="send a text!!!" id="sendtxt"></textarea><input type="button" value=">>" onclick="send()"/><br>

<div id="content">

<textarea>This text is going to refresh, when you click the button. change it and see it go back to normal</textarea>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you modify `innerHTML` as you've been doing by appending new content to an element, the element is re-rendered with the new HTML.

So, why not create an additional element inside it to hold your changing content while not interfering with what's outside of it?

I did this by creating a `#changing` div below. Live demo:

```js
function send() {
  $('changing').innerHTML += "<br>" + $('sendtxt').value;
  $('sendtxt').value = "";
}

function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}

iframe {
  width: 30%;
  height: calc(30%);
}

textarea,
input {
  display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 50px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  margin: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="send a text!!!" id="sendtxt"></textarea><input type="button" value=">>" onclick="send()" /><br>

<div id="content">

  <iframe src="http://www.bitwinent.com/games/blue/index.html">HTML NOT SUPPORTED</iframe>
  <textarea>[the iframe doens't seem to work in here] This text is going to refresh, when you click the button. change it and see it go back to normal</textarea>
  
  <div id="changing"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: i can't do that, because, the iframe itself can be added using the textarea (some sort of bbcode) here on the chat.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you update the `innerHTML` property, the browser destroys the existing DOM nodes, parses the string of HTML and creates new DOM nodes for them which are added as children of the node you set the `.innerHTML` of.

This will have the effect of reloading the iframe and resetting the textarea to the original value every time.

Instead, create a dedicated div after the textarea and modify the `innerHTML` of that instead.

Comment: i know this effect of dom replacing, i just wanted this could be possible. the problem is, i can't create a dedicated div just for it, because the iframe and the textarea themselves area supposed to be part of the changing div (the iframe can be added to the chat log, using some "bbcode" here on the chat)

Comment: Great minds - we posted pretty much identical answers within about 20 seconds of one another.

Comment: I made some changes on the snippet (if you send ":custom:" instead of a text, it will append an <textarea>, that also resets when send a new message. Isn't there any way of "saving" the content state?